# How to align Height and text in a Carousal in ASP.Net MVC 5 application

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I am a beginner and trying to implement Twitter Bootstrap Carousal, and I have two requirements.

1. Carousal/Image should be of the Height of the screen/browser (No Scrolling): No matter what the screen size is.
2. Text in the Carousal should be in the center irrespective of the screen size.

Below is standard Carousal for Bootstrap [Carousal by Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel2&stacked=h):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/15.jpeg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Los Angeles</h1>
                <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/20.jpeg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Chicago</h3>
                <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/10.jpeg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>New York</h3>
                <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Issue with above code:

1. Text is shown at the bottom (Need to scroll for that).
2. To see the entire Image/Carousal user has to scroll. **Not sure why this happens**

[image]

Attempt made by me:

1. I set the height is set to `515 px`;
2. Added CSS below:

   ```
   .item{
       position: relative;
   }

   .carousel-caption
   {
       top:35%;
       position: absolute;
   }
   ```

   ```
   <div class="item active" style="height:515px">
       <img src="~/Content/Images/15.jpeg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
       <div class="carousel-caption">
           <h1>Los Angeles</h1>
           <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Output:

[image]

**So far so Good**

But when I decrease the size of browser this is what I get:

[image]

**Expected Behaviour:**

[image]

Comment: In the 2nd image, you have no scrollbar, but the bottom 1/3 of the image is not visible - its not clear why you want to chop of the image like that

Comment: Ohhh. I did not notice that. :-|. I thought setting the height rendered the images (and made it small). I did not realize that it got chopped off. :-|

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Is there any way I can tell the carousal/image to render till the browser's height and not exceed?

Comment: Something like https://www.loom.co/

Comment: First to explain what your seeing - your image is 100% wide (but in a container that is 100% wide but only 515px high. In the 2nd image, the actual image height is about 700px high so the bottom is chopped off. In the 3rd image you have reduced the width but the ratio stays the same so the image is now about 300px high. But you text is positioned relative to the container, not the image

Comment: If you reduce the width of the browser window on that site, then image is cropped to the left and right (its not 100% as you want)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155800/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Can you kindly help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934301/how-to-track-asp-net-mvc-web-app-using-google-analytics-when-multiple-subdomains

Comment: Have not seen you for a while :) I have not used Google Analytics so wont be able to help on that one

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's alright. :)  Yes I have been not very active of late. I am glad that you decided to stay with SO and still helping junior developers. :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke; Please can you help me with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027690/how-to-incorporate-a-third-party-api-call-during-build-time-in-asp-net-mvc-appli

Comment: I see that you have accepted an answer so I assume its now resolved

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes.. thank you for your response.. :) so happy to see you active on SO. :)