# How to incorporate a third party api call during build time in ASP.Net MVC Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, msbuild-task

Ok, here is my story.

I have a *ASP.Net MVC Web Application* which works fine. But it needs some *.resx* file (some translated culture/language) file which comes by making an `API Call to a third party end point`. These *.resx* file needs to be brought in the application's corresponding folder *`everytime my web project builds`*. Because these resx file may change at the third party location so I need to get *fresh file* every time I run a build on my web application.

**Project 1:** So till now I have a MVC Web application which runs just fine. (Main Application)

**Project 2:** I have created another small console application (just a basic one) which has one end point which makes call to third party and gets the .resx file and saves to a location.

**Question 1:**

In order to accomplish what I want do I need to have a separate Project 2, which will make an third party call and copy the file to the Project 1 corresponding directory.

**Question 2:**

Project 2 which calls the third party needs to be console application or mvc application or what? I am not sure

**Question 3:**

Am I going in the right direction. All I want it when my **project 1** builds, I want to call a third party API and download some files to a particular folder.

**Question 4:**

Do I need to play with MS-Build to execute Project 2. exe and then Project 1.exe. so that files are there when project 1.exe starts building?

**Question 5:**

Do I really needan altogether separate project just to make the API CALL to get the resx file?

Please guide me.

Project 2 Code:

```
     class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => CallHttp());
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
    // Simple async function returning a string...
    static public async void CallHttp()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.crowdin.com/");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/project/refele/download/all.zip?key=f23e2c91833c0de737");
        using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@".\..\..\alpha\test.zip", FileMode.Create))
            await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(@".\..\..\alpha\test.zip", @".\..\..\beta");
    }

}
```

Comment: Would a post-build event satisfy your needs?

Comment: I think yes. But to be honest I don’t know post-build and all. I am a newbie. But I think it should work. Please help me.

Comment: I would avoid hard-coding strings in your HttpClient method.  You could pass those in as arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project1 csproj file you can specify a post-built event in the follwing manner:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>
    Call "FullyResolvedPathToYour.exe" "Arg1" "Arg2"
  </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I don't know how your exe is called, so you'll have adjust to meet your requirements.  Also note you have Visual Studio environment variables and system environment variables available to you in this format:  `$(Variable)`

For more information on this concept, you can read here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2017

Comment: I think then I should just make a simple console app and add the api call there, create the exe and call the post-build. I am assuming this post-build will run this exe and will run the "Main" and I will be able to put the resx file at the correct location of my Main ASP.Net Web Application to use.

Comment: `Call "C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Console\Console\bin\Debug\Console.exe"` I added this in POST-Build event but nothing happened, when I built the Parent Project

Comment: Do I need to have bat file or something?

Comment: Help is going to be limited since nobody knows what Console.exe is or how it should be called.  Are there any error codes in the build output window after building your project?

Comment: I added the code in my original question. Kindly see it once. Also when I built the parent project there is no exception

Comment: System.Console.Readline() will wait for user input, so you probably need to get rid of that.  I would also check your running processes, there might be a few abandoned instances of it still running.

Comment: If I dont put "System.Console.Readline()" then my code just executes and file does not get downloaded. But when I put this code, then file downloads properly. :-|

Comment: Yes you're executing the task without waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178810/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-parrish-husband).

Answer (score 2):

You can make API calls to an endpoint using CURL if you want. So you don't have to write a custom exe file to download your resx. The usage of that is beyond this answer. I'm no expert in that. Anyways, you can call it either before your after your csproj file builds.

If you call the API after your build, don't use a `<PostBuildEvent>`. It's like taking a hammer to surgery. Overkill. Use a Target instead.

```
<Target Name="Call your Stuff" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="FullyResolvedPathToYour.EXE arg1 arg2 etc" WorkingDirectory="..." />
</Target>
```

If you need to call this target before your build, just change `AfterTargets` to `BeforeTargets`
There is plenty of documentation for msbuild on msdn for Targets.

Comment: "don't use a. ", Did you miss some wordings there?

Comment: So everytime I build my application, "Call your stuff" will get executed right? All I need to do it add "Call your Stuff" in <DefaultTarget> lists right, separated by semicolon?

Comment: You don't need to add "Call your stuff" to anything. MSBuild does it all for you. But in your case, I think you should get your updated resx files BEFORE you build not after.

Comment: Let me add, that we also use crowdin translations. I too once wrote a tool to download the updated resx files from their website. But I switched over to using their command line tool instead.

Comment: I understood. Thank you so much for your inputs. I will definitely look into using cURL. I am a beginner and I initially want it to get going. :) . So if I am not mistaken all I need to do is add your code snippet and change the "AfterTargets" to "Before Targets" and I should be good to go. But there is one more thing to it. I want the "FullyResolvPathTo.EXE" this exe to be created too, when I build my parent solution. I mean now with your changes I will be able to run the exe while building the parent solution, but I want 2 generate fresh FullyResolvPathTo.exe too everything parent is build

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178872/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-c-johnson).